# IE6 & 7 only - CSS/jQuery animation bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

Have been working non-stop for last 8 hours and so don't have enough energy to fix this IE6/7 only bug. Can some jQuery /CSS experts please help out?

Access this url using any browser other than IE6/7:

http://www.sumanasa.com/technews

On the topmost right hand corner, a) click on the Quick guide link to show a quick guide and b) click it again to hide it. This behaviour uses jQuery and works fine in all browsers except IE6/7. The animation works fine in IE8. The HTML markup is XHTML Transitional. Any ideas on how to solve this bug?

Comment: FYI: jquery 1.4.3 is out. (You appear to be using 1.4.2) If you reference the newer version, you should get some performance improvements and bug fixes but I don't know about it fixing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to fix it by applying position:relative to the top element that was being slid down as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the visiblity and the display properties ... which are you using and which uses jquery, I heard a trouble in there with jQuery and IE6 for display/visibility.
Maybe appling both on you CSS you can have it working in all version browsers

Comment: I have implemented it very similar to what they have in their documentation: http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/. visibility:hidden makes things worse.